# Why does this MySQL stored function return null?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-functions

can anybody explain, why the following MySQL stored function returns always null? If I replace `exchange_rate` within `SET @dollar = euro * exchange_rate;` by 1.1013 it works great.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS euro_to_dollar;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION euro_to_dollar(euro double) returns double
BEGIN
  DECLARE dollar double;
  DECLARE exchange_rate double;
  SET @exchange_rate = 1.1013;
  SET @dollar = euro * exchange_rate;
  RETURN @dollar;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You are mixing different variables . . . try `SET @dollar = euro * @exchange_rate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make reference to @exchange_rate like this:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS euro_to_dollar;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION euro_to_dollar(euro double) returns double
BEGIN
  DECLARE dollar double;
  DECLARE exchange_rate double;
  SET @exchange_rate = 1.1013;
  SET @dollar = euro * @exchange_rate;
  RETURN @dollar;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that was the solution! :)